# Empty database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert values in "Navn" row and "Varenr" row in the DB table, when I'm clicking on a button. I have following code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            try
            { 
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
            cm.Connection = cn;
            string col1 = textBox2.Text;
            string col2 = textBox3.Text;

            //generate sql statement
            cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ProduktTable (Navn,Varenr) VALUES (@col1,@col2)";
            //add some SqlParameters
            SqlParameter sp_add_col1 = new SqlParameter();
            sp_add_col1.ParameterName = "@col1";
            //data type in sqlserver
            sp_add_col1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            //if your data type is not number,this property must set
            //sp_add_col1.Size = 20;
            sp_add_col1.Value = textBox2.Text;
            //add parameter into collections
            cm.Parameters.Add(sp_add_col1);
            //in your insert into statement, there are how many parameter, you must write the number of parameter
            SqlParameter sp_add_col2 = new SqlParameter();
            sp_add_col2.ParameterName = "@col2";
            //data type in sqlserver
            sp_add_col2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            //if your data type is not number,this property must set
            //sp_add_col2.Size = 20;
            sp_add_col2.Value = textBox2.Text;
            //add parameter into collections
            cm.Parameters.Add(sp_add_col2);

            //open the DB to execute sql
            cn.Open();
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }                
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, my data table is still empty:

[image]

I have set a breakpoint on the ExecuteNonQuery function, and it is triggered, when pressing on the button:

[image]

My table definition:

[image]

Comment: So there's no exception?

Comment: Well, what happens when you debug it?

Comment: No. There is no exception.

Comment: What kind of debugging do you suggest in this case ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, but your `ParameterName` property is supposed to be set to just the name of the parameter, minus `@`, I think.

Comment: So in your case, `sp_add_col1.ParameterName = "col1";`.

Comment: Yes. I have included my DB table, since this could be the issue perhaps. I have also tried an another procedure, but the same issue happened. The table does not register any data.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you can simplify adding parameters using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)`.

Comment: I think the problem is with how you're adding your prepared statement parameters, not the table. Have you tried what I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: Hi Asad. Can you be more specific on how you want me to change the Parameter name ?. I did not understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string is causing this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

`|DataDirectory|` Your database that is being updated in this method is in your App Data Directory while the one you are trying to retrieve data from is in your project folder...

`|DataDirectory|` is a substitution string that indicates the path to the database. `DataDirectory` also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy an application. For my PC my App Data Directory is:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\...
```

If you browse to this location and then go to following folders

```
...\Local\Apps\2.0\Data
```

You will be able to find your particular application directory probably stored with your assembly name, or some hash when you go there you will find it the database there is being updated just fine. This connection string is best for deployment.

You can also try this:

[image]

If you notice that Server Explorer is detecting all the databases on my PC and you can notice that there are couple of `MINDMUSCLE.MDF` files but all are at different paths, this is because there is one file in `DEBUG` directory, one in my `PROJECT` directory, one in my `APP DATA` directory. The ones starting with the numbers are stored in my `APP DATA` directories... If you select your respective database file and then run the `SELECT` query against it, you will get your data.

I made a [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/fkbullet11/con-stringslideshare) some time ago. May be it will help you:

Answer (score 1):

Check the value that ExecuteNonQuery is returning. It should return an int with the number of records affected by the SQL statement.

If it comes back with a value other than 0, then you know a record is being inserted somewhere. Before you close the connection, run a SQL query against the table to select all of the records and see if they come back through the code.

```
SELECT * FROM ProduktTable
```

If you get some records, then you may want to double check the database you're looking at through the IDE and the one your inserting records into through the code. It could be possible that you've got two different databases and you're querying one while inserting into another one.

Those are the steps that I would go through to help narrow down the issue and sounds like something I've probably done before. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I think that the data is stored into a copy of my database located under bin\Debug folder during the execution. Do you have any ide of how to store the data into my original database located in my project folder.